# Function fails when called by other function

Tags: jquery

fairly new to jQuery so bear with me.

I am having trouble getting the results of one function over to another an executing it.

Then the point is to pass the text as a var to the function populateMessage() and it writes the text to a text box.

I can get the text and it does get passed to the populateMessage function but the function never fully executes and the text box is not populated. If I wrap the populateMessage function in document.ready and have it write something like .text('test'); it will work.

How can I make this work?

Thanks for the help

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getClickedInvite();
});

//gets clicked item template and sends it to message box

function getClickedInvite() {
    $('.card').click(function () {
        var selectedMessage = $(this).text();
        alert(selectedMessage);
        populateMessage(selectedMessage);
    });
}

function populateMessage(selectedMessage) { 
    alert(selectedMessage + ' has been sent to the message box ')
    var inviteMessageBoxId = $('#inviteMessageBox').find('textarea').attr('id');
    alert(inviteMessageBoxId);
    $('#' + inviteMessageBoxId).text(selectedMessage);
}
```

Comment: Do you get an alert when you click on a member of the `.card` class?

Comment: I cleaned up the code based on a answer that seems to have been removed from the answer list. I moved the getClickedInvite into the doc ready and it seems work. I think the big problem is my environment where the textare is a HTML editor. When the editor is in plain textarea it works but when it is in rich editor mode it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to extend the function like that. And if you read the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/find/), it says

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

SO [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) always does not return a single element.

```
$('#inviteMessageBox').find('textarea')[0].text(selectedMessage);
```

Or, if getting `id` is really that necessary then

```
var id = $('#inviteMessageBox').find('textarea')[0].attr('id');
$("#"+id").text(selectedMessage);
```

Comment: As I mentioned in a different comment I am on DotNetNuke and the textarea is a HTML editor control so when it renders the element ID is prepended with DNN control 'junk' so I have to first get the dynamic id of the textarea. I tried replacing with what you have but it did not work..with my limited knowledge

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't require you to reference everything by 'id', so you can change your `populateMessage` function to something like this:

```
function populateMessage(selectedMessage) {
    $('#inviteMessageBox')
        .find('textarea')
        .text(selectedMessage);
}
```

Comment: thanks. my case is that I use dotnetnuke and the textbox (html editor) is a control. At rendering the id is prepended with a bunch of DNN related 'junk' so I have to get the dynamically created ID first...

Answer (score 0):

The reason this only works when called after `$(document).ready()` is because when you are attempting to bind the click event to all elements with the class `.card` they don't actually exist on the page yet, so the binding fails.

When after `$(document).ready();` the DOM has been written fully and you can be confident all elements are on the page an ready to accept event to be bound to them.

The best way to get around this is to define your functions straight away and bind them to elements once you know the document is ready, like so:

```
function sayHello() {
    alert('hello');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button1').click(sayHello);
    $('.button2').click(sayHello);
    $('.button3').click(sayHello);
});
```

This method should keep your code much cleaner. Reference all functions first and bind events last.

Comment: @MarkHollas thanks. Make sure you mark the best answer and +1 helpful ones.